# Injecting items in Android browsers caches

Tags: java, android, google-chrome, firefox, caching

I am currently trying to find a way to programatically inject items into a mobile browser's cach on Android devices. The browser type doesn't matter, it can be Firefox, Chrome, Android's built in browser, etc.. Is there any documentation or examples of ways to programatically  inject objects into the browsers of Android devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an answer, just a heads up. Seeing that your question is tagged `java`, I assume you want to do this from an application, and not from the browser. I'm pretty sure that's impossible, because each Android app is running in it's sandbox. Communication between apps is done through Intents and [IPC](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html). In both cases, you are limited by what the target app is offering support for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use proxy, to get this structure :

Client => Your APK => Server

(Like this [application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.proxyserver&hl=fr)).

With your APK you can choose file to send.

Comment: Could you evaluate a litte more on how this would achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Like already mentioned by Corneliu, its impossible for an normal android app to write into the data section of another app.

Although it should work when the phone is rooted. Apps like TitaniumBackup which require root can read and write the data saved by other apps. You can use TianiumBackup to make a backup of the browsers and look in the *.tar.gz file for the internal data structures and the SQLite DB files...